# How would I do a join of three tables with sql server

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out what to do here. Look at these tables:

**users**

id, username, password

**books**

id, title

**users_books**

bookID, userID

How would one join these together? If I for example wanted to see user 47's books?

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, Tommy. This sounds like a homework question. That's ok, but could you say what you tried, and what problems you had? It really sounds like you're trying to get someone to do it all for you, which some people don't like. They like to think you tried first.

Comment: It also has a fairly non-specific subject line. There are probably several thousand questions on SO right now that would fit with this very same subject line! It would be much better if you said "how would I do a join of three tables with sql server".

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it is a homework then instead of giving fish everyday, teaching how to fish would be more helpful.

I hope the following references would aid in understanding SQL joins-

http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

As far as your join query is concerned, response given by 'm-sharp' should give you the correct answer.

cheers

Comment: Andriyev: Thanks for the fishing lessons! Lack of lessons is what I meant.

Comment: Yes John. I do agree with your comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, this query should work.

```
select books.title

from books, users_books

where books.id = users_books.bookID and users_books.id = 47
```

Comment: Oh, well. I hope this wasn't homework, or someone will have to help him out tomorrow as well.

Comment: My opinion is that people who ask homework questions without tagging them homework should just be given the answer. I have no qualms about giving them direct answers since this has the advantage of making it harder for them to put me out of work later (since they're invariably stupid). :-)

Comment: I'd suggest you might have waited long enough for him to decide to answer. BTW, IMHO there's just as much risk of him putting you out of work. The problem is, once he's taken someone else's job, he won't be able to do it, because we've enabled him to get by without learning anything. I see a lot of questions here (though more elsewhere) by people who really shouldn't be doing those jobs (this is the polite version).

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.title from users_books ub 
  join books b on b.id = ub.bookID 
  where ub.userID = 47
```

Comment: Joel,  I don't see how this is different from m-sharp's answer.

Comment: It doesn't use implied joins, for one thing.

Comment: "from books, users_books" is a join, with a different syntax.

Comment: It has lower precedence (in mysql, at least) than an actual join.  For a problem this simple, it's a matter of taste.  If more tables need to be added in, being explicit can help avoid weird errors, and (for me) make it more readable.

Anyway, feel free to nuke my answer if you think it's the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers are joining *three* tables (your question heading states three but your body only needs two), I'll give you a three table version.

To do that I assume you have the username of the user rather than the ID. In that case, you can do:

```
select
    u.id as user_id,
    u.username as user_name,
    b.id as book_id,
    b.title as book_title
from
    users u,
    books b.
    user_books ub
where u.username = 'username-of-user-47'
and   u.id = ub.userID
and   b.id = ub.bookID
```

This sort of thing can also be done with explicit `JOIN`s but I prefer the "old school" SQL ways especially when the DBMS is clever enough to optimize it in the same manner, such as my beloved DB2/z :-)